# Why am I getting 'ValueError: Columns must be same length as key' When replacing Outliers with Median

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, data-cleaning, outliers

I am tryin to run this loop on my dataframe to get rid of my outliers and replacing them with the median, but I am running into this problem: 'ValueError: Columns must be same length as key'.
This is the code that I am using on my DataFrame:

```py
for j in df2.columns:  
    Q1 = df2[[j]].quantile(q = 0.25)  
    Q3 = df2[[j]].quantile(q = 0.75)
    
    lower_outliers = Q1 - 1.5*(Q3 - Q1)  
    upper_outliers = Q3 + 1.5*(Q3 - Q1)
    
    up_out_count = df2[df2[[j]]>upper_outliers][[j]].count()
    lo_out_count = df2[df2[[j]]<lower_outliers][[j]].count()
    
    tot_out_count = up_out_count + lo_out_count
    tot_data = df2[[j]].count()
    percent = (tot_out_count / tot_data)*100
    
    print(f'Number of outliers in '+ j +' upper: ', up_out_count)
    print(f'Number of outliers in '+ j +' lower: ', lo_out_count)
    print(f'The percentage of outliers in '+ j +' is: ', percent,'\n\n')

    median = df2[[j]].median()
    df[[j]] = np.where(df[[j]] > upper_outliers , median, np.where(df2[[j]] < lower_outliers, median, df[[j]]))
```

I have also already used this too and it also didn't work:

```py
    #df[[j]] = np.where(df2[[j]] < lower_outliers, median, df2[[j]])         
    #df[[j]] = np.where(df2[[j]] > upper_outliers, median, df2[[j]]) 
    #df[[j]] = df[[j]].replace(df2[[j]] < lower_outliers, median)
    #df[[j]] = df[[j]].replace(df2[[j]] > upper_outliers, median)
```

Maybe to note I am using double [[]] since I kept running into scaler vs. vector problems.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand correctly what you want to do. So this is what I understand:

- You have a dataframe with many columns
- In each column, you want to replace the values that are outside of the range of the quartile (0.25, 0.75) with the mean of that column.

This is the code that represent that:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columns_names = list("abcdefgh")
nb_samples = 10
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.default_rng().uniform(low=1.0, high=100.0, size=(nb_samples, len(columns_names))), columns=columns_names)

quantile_range = (0.25, 0.75)

print('Original dataframe:')
print(df2)

print('\nMean:')
print(df2.mean())

def remove_outliers(current_column):
    current_mean = current_column.mean(axis=0)
    outlier_range = current_column.quantile(quantile_range)

    return current_column.where(
        (current_column >= outlier_range[quantile_range[0]]) & (current_column <= outlier_range[quantile_range[1]]), 
        current_mean
    )

print('\nOutliers replaced:')
print(df2.apply(remove_outliers))

nb_lower_outliers = df2.apply(lambda column: len(column[column <= column.quantile(quantile_range[0])]))
print('\nNumber of outliers (lower):')
print(nb_lower_outliers)

nb_upper_outliers = df2.apply(lambda column: len(column[column >= column.quantile(quantile_range[1])]))
print('\nNumber of outliers (upper):')
print(nb_upper_outliers)

outliers_percentage = (nb_lower_outliers + nb_upper_outliers) * 100 / len(df2)
print('\nPercentage of outliers:')
print(outliers_percentage)
```

Does that make sense with what you are trying to do?